# Testing with Grunt & Mocha: 'require' not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, mocha.js

I'm working on an application and I want to write some tests on my database.

When I want to run my test code, it gives me the following error in my *dbtest.js* file:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require
```

**UPDATE:**

I had no idea I had to use `require.js`, but now I have downloaded it, but I don't know how to configure it. What changes do I need to make to get this working?

Here are my files:

**dbtest.js**

```
var Database = require(['./../server/database.js'])
describe('Database', function() {
    var db = new Database();
    ...
    ...
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Mocha Spec Runner</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../vendor/mocha.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mocha"></div>
        <script src="../vendor/mocha.js"></script>
        <script>mocha.setup('bdd')</script>
        <script src="../vendor/chai.js"></script>
        <script>
            var assert = chai.assert;
            var expect = chai.expect;
            var should = chai.should();
        </script>
        <script src="../vendor/require.js"></script>

        <!-- include source files here... -->

        <!-- include spec files here... -->
        <script src="../dbtest.js"></script>

        <script>
        if (window.mochaPhantomJS) { 
            mochaPhantomJS.run();
        } else { 
            mocha.run();
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**testapp.js (Express app):**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var http = require('http');

var app = express();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('html', require('jade').renderFile);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views')));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index.html');
});

// start up server
var PORT = 3001;

var server = http.createServer( app ).listen( PORT, function() {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + PORT);
});
```

**Gruntfile.js**

```
// Express Config
    express: {
        options: {
          // Override defaults here
        },
        dev: {
            options: {
                port: 3000,
                script: 'app.js'
            }
        },
        test: {
            options: {
                port: 3001,
                script: 'test/testapp.js'
            }
        }
    },

mocha_phantomjs: {
        options: {
            'reporter': 'spec'
        },
        all: ['test/views/**/*.html']
    },

//Test
grunt.registerTask('test', 'Run the tests.', [
    'clean:server',
    'jshint:test',
    'express:test',
    //'open:test',
    'mocha_phantomjs'
]);
```

Comment: Looks like you didn't include the `require.js` library in your HTML file... which is then used by `dbtest.js`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @jakerella Could you show me how I need to configure `require.js`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a browser there is no `require` function for you to use. If you want to load modules, you should use a library like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) or [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) to load your modules. Mocha does not provide such functionality by itself.

Comment: I had no idea about this. I'm kind of new to this. I've downloaded `RequireJS`. Could you demonstrate how I use this?